# Converge (fixed point) syntax difference in q and k

Tags: kdb, k

We should use square brackets when flattering all levels in list:

```
q)b:(1 2;(3 4;5 6);7;8)
q)raze/[b]               / flatten all levels
1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8
q)raze/b
'/
  [0]  raze/b
```

But why one forced to use `raze/[b]` for Converge syntax instead of simple `raze/b`?

- Upd

Why this syntax works in `k`, for example `{x+y}/1 2 3` but doesn't work in `q`?

My assumption that it's been made to prevent qbies errors when using `/` adverb instead of `%`. I think there may be a discussion about it in some dev channel, but I've found only Shakti discussion group for now at https://groups.google.com/forum/#!forum/shaktidb, and kx.com also shutted down community wiki, so I don't know where to find an additional info - asking here

- Upd2

The `/` is quite overloaded in `k` too: see (not official ref though) https://github.com/JohnEarnest/ok/blob/gh-pages/docs/Manual.md#over - `over`, `fixedpoint`, `for` and `while`. Pretty the same as in `q`, right? But why the interpreter 'ban' the `k` syntax in `q` context, - is there a technical reason why `q` can't recognise a user intention as it `k` does?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The reason that, say, `cos/1` works in `k` but not `q` is that `q` has no ambivalence. That is to say that all `q` operators are not overloaded on valence, as noted in section 6.1.2 in [q4m](https://code.kx.com/q4m3/6_Functions/#612-function-notation-and-terminology).

With any of `q`'s adverbs (each:`'`, over:`/` scan:`\`, prior:`:`, eachright:`/:`, eachleft:`\:`) the resulting derivative function is interpreted by `q` to be dyadic, unless you uses []'s to specifically pass one argument.

For the example above `q` interprets `cos/` as [do](https://code.kx.com/q/ref/accumulators/#do) rather than [converge](https://code.kx.com/q/ref/accumulators/#converge) and so requires the left argument specifying the number of iterations (Note the results of `0 cos/ 1`, `1 cos/ 1`, `2 cos/ 1`, etc.). The preferred way to resolve is to use []'s: `cos/[1]`.

`(cos/) 1` works because user defined functions can never use infix notation, so the expression is automatically interpreted as applying monadically. This is also why `2 (cos/) 1` fails. To resolve this you would again have to use []'s: `(cos/)[2;1]`.

Comment: Oh, that's pretty exhaustively! After the first reading of q4m I've marked pretty much unclear places, and one of them is exactly you've pointed out in section 6.1.2. Thank you very much!

Answer (score 2):

You don't necessarily need square brackets here. You could use

`(raze/)b`

if you do not want to use square brackets around `b`.  The way you are using over ( or `/`) without the brackets around `b` requires the parenthesis around `raze/b` if you do not specify the initial value of the accumulator.  This is because the q interpreter needs to know that you are applying `raze/` to the list `b` rather than applying `/` to the list first (which is why a `'/` error is thrown) then `raze` after (reading the code from right to left).

More info on using `/` can be found here: https://code.kx.com/q4m3/6_Functions/#676-over-for-accumulation

Comment: Thank you! Now it's pretty clear that `[]` interpreted as a `raze/` param, or adverb `/` acts as a function modifier bundled with function together `(raze/)`. But the last thing - why this syntax works in `k`, for example `{x+y}/1 2 3` but doesn't work in `q`?

Comment: Rob, what is the effect of applying `/` to the list first? How `q` interprets this?

Comment: It is the case that the `/` is quite overloaded in q.  See here for all of the syntax and semantics of `/`:  https://code.kx.com/q/ref/overloads/#slash

For the specific use of converge (as you are doing), it will not produce expected output unless you use `(raze/)b` or `raze/[b]`, otherwise the q interpreter will not know what to do when it reaches `/`.

Comment: @egor7 When used as an adverb a slash symbol must be adjacent to its operand, i.e. follow it, so this expression is not valid it q: `/1 2 3` as there's nothing to apply `/` to.